# Running Total using a From TextBox

Tags: c#

Trying to get a running total when adding a number in a textbox and then clicking on a button.

```
using System;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FixedDebugThree3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // This declaration is in the correct place.
        // total is outside the method so it can remain a running total.
        double total = 0;
        private void TotalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double num = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1);
            total = num;
            outputLabel.Text = "Running total:" + );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this at the end of the last line + )

Comment: `total += num;`

Comment: You need something after the plus sign in your code. As it is, it won't compile. You probably want to change the previous line to `total += num;` to get the total. Then, you want to concatenate your total to your "running total". Your total is a double, so you'll need to convert it to a string. Luckily, an override of `object.ToString` will do that for you. Consider changing you conversion of your text box contents to us `double.TryParse` instead of `Conver.ToDouble`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues with your code, I've commented:

```
using System;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FixedDebugThree3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //declare class-wide variable to hold running total
        private double total = 0;
        private void TotalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //c# 7 syntax allows us to neatly declare a "num" variable as part of the out parameter
            //your original code tried to convert the whole textbox to double. You need to use the .Text
            if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var num))
            {
               total += num;
               outputLabel.Text = "Running total:" + total);
            } else { // if parsing the number failed- (write defensive code that consumes user input)
               outputLabel.Text = "Please enter a valid number. Current Running total:" + total);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're on c#6 or earlier then the syntax above will need tweaking to:

```
double num;
if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num)) {
```